How to implement simple allocator for use with STL containers?
I have an allocator, that fine works with std::vector, but has compile errors with std::basic_string. There is my code:
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct MyAllocator {
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef T* pointer;
    typedef T* const const_pointer;
    typedef T& reference;
    typedef T const& const_reference;
    typedef std::size_t size_type;
    typedef std::ptrdiff_t difference_type;
    MyAllocator() = default;

    template <typename U>
    MyAllocator(const MyAllocator<U>&) {}

    template <typename U>
    struct rebind {
        typedef MyAllocator<U> other;
    };

    pointer allocate(size_t n) {
        void* chunk = ::operator new(n * sizeof(value_type));
        if (chunk == nullptr) {
            throw std::bad_alloc();
        }
        return static_cast<pointer>(chunk);
    }

    void deallocate(pointer p, size_t n) {
        ::operator delete(p);
    }
    template <typename... Args>
    void construct(void* p, Args&&... args) {
        ::new(p) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    void destroy(pointer p) {
        p->~T();
    }
    bool operator==(const MyAllocator&) const {
        return true;
    }
    bool operator!=(const MyAllocator&) const {
        return false;
    }
};

typedef std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, MyAllocator<char>> my_string;

int main() {
    #if defined(V_TEST)
    std::vector<int, MyAllocator<int>> v_test = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    std::cout << "v_test.size() = " << v_test.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "v_test.capacity() = " << v_test.capacity() << std::endl;
    v_test.push_back(7);
    v_test.push_back(8);
    std::cout << "v_test.size() = " << v_test.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "v_test.capacity() = " << v_test.capacity() << std::endl;
    #elif defined(S_TEST)
    my_string s = "Hello world";
    std::cout << "s.size() = " << s.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "s.capacity() = " << s.capacity() << std::endl;
    s += " Hello again";
    std::cout << "s.size() = " << s.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "s.capacity() = " << s.capacity() << std::endl;
    #endif
    return 0;
}

When I try to compile with S_TEST flag it has compile error:
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/stl_iterator.h: In instantiation of 'class __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char* const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, MyAllocator<char> > >':
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/basic_string.tcc:243:21:   required from 'void std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::_M_construct(_InIterator, _InIterator, std::forward_iterator_tag) [with _FwdIterator = const char*; _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = MyAllocator<char>]'
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/basic_string.h:639:14:   required from 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string(const _CharT*, const _Alloc&) [with <template-parameter-2-1> = MyAllocator<char>; _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = MyAllocator<char>]'
alloc_EXAMPLE.cpp:64:19:   required from here
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/stl_iterator.h:1062:57: error: no type named 'iterator_category' in '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char* const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, MyAllocator<char> > >::__traits_type' {aka 'struct std::iterator_traits<char* const>'}
 1062 |       typedef typename __traits_type::iterator_category iterator_category;
      |                                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/stl_iterator.h:1063:57: error: no type named 'value_type' in '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char* const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, MyAllocator<char> > >::__traits_type' {aka 'struct std::iterator_traits<char* const>'}
 1063 |       typedef typename __traits_type::value_type        value_type;
      |                                                         ^~~~~~~~~~
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/stl_iterator.h:1064:57: error: no type named 'difference_type' in '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char* const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, MyAllocator<char> > >::__traits_type' {aka 'struct std::iterator_traits<char* const>'}
 1064 |       typedef typename __traits_type::difference_type   difference_type;
      |                                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/stl_iterator.h:1065:57: error: no type named 'reference' in '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char* const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, MyAllocator<char> > >::__traits_type' {aka 'struct std::iterator_traits<char* const>'}
 1065 |       typedef typename __traits_type::reference         reference;
      |                                                         ^~~~~~~~~
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/stl_iterator.h:1066:57: error: no type named 'pointer' in '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char* const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, MyAllocator<char> > >::__traits_type' {aka 'struct std::iterator_traits<char* const>'}
 1066 |       typedef typename __traits_type::pointer           pointer;
In file included from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/13.2.0/string:54,
                 from alloc_EXAMPLE.cpp:2:
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/basic_string.h: In instantiation of 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::const_pointer std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::_M_local_data() const [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = MyAllocator<char>; const_pointer = char* const]':
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/basic_string.h:264:32:   required from 'bool std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::_M_is_local() const [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = MyAllocator<char>]'
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/basic_string.h:1159:9:   required from 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::capacity() const [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = MyAllocator<char>; size_type = long long unsigned int]'
alloc_EXAMPLE.cpp:66:49:   required from here
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/basic_string.h:241:62: error: 'pointer_to' is not a member of 'std::pointer_traits<char* const>'
  241 |         return std::pointer_traits<const_pointer>::pointer_to(*_M_local_buf);

I satisfy all requirements for allocator, I suppose and cannot understand, why iteratot errors generated. Give me some advice, what am I miss? Thanks in advance!

typedef T* const const_pointer; should be typedef T const* const_pointer;

const_pointer should be const T*, not T* const. You can just drop all the typedefs except value_type, they all have suitable defaults.

Useful reference in case you have not seen it before.

thanks, it really work. const pointer an pointer to const confuse me after all

@StasFurmavnin Think of it this way, depending on which side of * const happens to be, it is either a pointer to a constant or a pointer which is constant - latter was true in your case.
